# I am not able to add put labels in 3d donut chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, donut-chart

I have created a D3 donut chart by using a code on codepen but I am unable to add the labels to it. I want the labels to be added on the side of every portion. For creating this donut chart I have used D3.js:

[image]

This is the code I have used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataset = [
    { name: 'Savings', count: 3250 },
    { name: 'Housing', count: 1707 },
    { name: 'Transportation', count: 377 },
    { name: 'Misc', count: 365 },
    { name: 'Insurance', count: 314 },
    { name: 'Utilities', count: 294 },
    { name: 'Student Loans', count: 262 },
    { name: 'Food', count: 250 },
    { name: 'Phone', count: 10 },





];

var total=0;

dataset.forEach(function(d){
    total+= d.count;
});


var pie=d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d){return d.count})
        .sort(null);


var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(dataset))
var w=300,h=300;

var outerRadiusArc=w/2;
var innerRadiusArc=100;
var shadowWidth=10;

var outerRadiusArcShadow=innerRadiusArc+1;
var innerRadiusArcShadow=innerRadiusArc-shadowWidth;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .range(['#f5e232', '#64eb34' , '#2d72e0', '#e3251b', '#d61be3', '#f0b00e', '#0ef0c3', '#e61240', '#db12e6']).domain(["Saving", "Housing", "Transportayion", "Misc", "Insurance", "Utilities", "Student Loan", "Food", "Phone"])
;

var svg=d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr({
            width:w,
            height:h,
            class:'shadow'
        }).append('g')
        .attr({
            transform:'translate('+w/2+','+h/2+')'
        });


var createChart=function(svg,outerRadius,innerRadius,fillFunction,className){

    var arc=d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(outerRadius)
            .outerRadius(innerRadius);

    var path=svg.selectAll('.'+className)
            .data(pie(dataset))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr({
                class:className,
                d:arc,
                fill:fillFunction
            });

    path.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, d);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
            });
};

createChart(svg,outerRadiusArc,innerRadiusArc,function(d,i){
    return color(d.data.name);
},'path1');

createChart(svg,outerRadiusArcShadow,innerRadiusArcShadow,function(d,i){
    var c=d3.hsl(color(d.data.name));
    return d3.hsl((c.h+5), (c.s -.07), (c.l -.15));
},'path2');

var addText= function (text,y,size) {
    svg.append('text')
            .text(text)
            .attr({
                'text-anchor':'middle',
                y:y
            })
            .style({
                fill:'black',
                'font-size':size,


            });
};


var addTexttwo= function (text,x,y,size) {
    svg.append('text')
            .text(text)
            .attr({
                'text-anchor':'middle',
                y:y,
                x:x,
            })
            .style({
                fill:'white',
                'font-size':size,


            });
};

var restOfTheData=function(){

    addText(function(){
        return "$6,830";
    },40,'30px');


    addText(function(){
        return "Shine's";
    },-20, '20px');

    addText(function(){
        return "Monthly Budget";
    },0, '20px');



};

setTimeout(restOfTheData,1000);


function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
    </script>
```

I want the result to look somewhat like this. With the labels on the side of the donut
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code puts the labels around the pie:

```
const textRadius = d => outerRadiusArc + (d.data.count < 50 ? 15 : 5);
const textX = d => textRadius(d) * Math.sin((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2);
const textY = d => textRadius(d) * -Math.cos((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2);
const textAnchor = d => (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
            
svg.selectAll('text.label')
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .classed('label', true)
  .text(d => d.data.name)
  .attr('x', textX)
  .attr('y', textY)
  .attr('text-anchor', textAnchor)
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
```

```js
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Savings', count: 3250 },
    { name: 'Housing', count: 1707 },
    { name: 'Transportation', count: 377 },
    { name: 'Misc', count: 365 },
    { name: 'Insurance', count: 314 },
    { name: 'Utilities', count: 294 },
    { name: 'Student Loans', count: 262 },
    { name: 'Food', count: 250 },
    { name: 'Phone', count: 10 },





];

var total=0;

dataset.forEach(function(d){
    total+= d.count;
});


var pie=d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d){return d.count})
        .sort(null);


var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(dataset))
var w=400,h=300;

var outerRadiusArc=120;
var innerRadiusArc=90;
var shadowWidth=10;

var outerRadiusArcShadow=innerRadiusArc+1;
var innerRadiusArcShadow=innerRadiusArc-shadowWidth;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .range(['red', '#f5e232', 'orange' , '#2d72e0', '#e3251b', '#d61be3', '#f0b00e', '#0ef0c3', '#e61240', '#db12e6']).domain(["Saving", "Housing", "Transportayion", "Misc", "Insurance", "Utilities", "Student Loan", "Food", "Phone"])
;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr({
            width:w,
            height:h,
            class:'shadow'
        }).append('g')
        .attr({
            transform:'translate('+w/2+','+h/2+')'
        });


var createChart=function(svg,outerRadius,innerRadius,fillFunction,className){

    var arc=d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(outerRadius)
            .outerRadius(innerRadius);

    var path=svg.selectAll('.'+className)
            .data(pie(dataset))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr({
                class:className,
                d:arc,
                fill:fillFunction
            });

    path.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, d);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
            })
            .each(d => {
              console.log(d);
            })
   const textRadius = d => outerRadiusArc + (d.data.count < 50 ? 15 : 5);
   const textX = d => textRadius(d) * Math.sin((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2);
   const textY = d => textRadius(d) * -Math.cos((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2);
   const textAnchor = d => (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
            
   svg.selectAll('text.label')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .classed('label', true)
    .text(d => d.data.name)
    .attr('x', textX)
    .attr('y', textY)
    .attr('text-anchor', textAnchor)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
   /*
   svg.selectAll('circle.point')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('point', true)
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('cx', textX)
    .attr('cy', textY)
     */                
};

createChart(svg,outerRadiusArc,innerRadiusArc,function(d,i){
    return color(d.data.name);
},'path1');

createChart(svg,outerRadiusArcShadow,innerRadiusArcShadow,function(d,i){
    var c=d3.hsl(color(d.data.name));
    return d3.hsl((c.h+5), (c.s -.07), (c.l -.15));
},'path2');

var addText= function (text,y,size) {
    svg.append('text')
            .text(text)
            .attr({
                'text-anchor':'middle',
                y:y
            })
            .style({
                fill:'black',
                'font-size':size,


            });
};


var addTexttwo= function (text,x,y,size) {
    svg.append('text')
            .text(text)
            .attr({
                'text-anchor':'middle',
                y:y,
                x:x,
            })
            .style({
                fill:'white',
                'font-size':size,


            });
};

var restOfTheData=function(){

    addText(function(){
        return "$6,830";
    },40,'30px');


    addText(function(){
        return "Shine's";
    },-20, '20px');

    addText(function(){
        return "Monthly Budget";
    },0, '20px');



};

setTimeout(restOfTheData,1000);


function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```css
.label {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" />
```